# Ubuntu22.04 with Intel i5-11320H‘s graph

Tags: boot, nomodeset

Today I am installing Ubuntu 2204 in laptop with i5-11320h, I must use the 'nomodeset' parameter at startup to display the graphical interface normally.

Does the parameter nomodeset cause other problems?

Is Iris Graph Driver not supported by the kernel?

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you do not say what kernel you are using no one can tell you if the graphic driver is in it or not.

Comment: I have full install of 22.04 on an external SSD that boots both my laptop with exactly same CPU/ Dell 5310 and on my Desktop with i5-12400. Default i915 driver just works. What brand/model system? Do you also have another video card/chip?

Comment: My kernel is 5.15.0-47-generic.
After I used 'i915.enable_psr=0' in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, problem solved.